# Entity Framework: auto-generate primary keys after initializing tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework (6) in a code-first arrangement to create a database and pre-populate it from a set of CSV files.  Because the tables are coming from another application, they already have primary keys, and relationships embedded in the data make reference to those keys.

For that reason I've been using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` when defining these tables, so that the PKs already in place get used.

However, after the data have been imported, I want to be able to add new records to the tables.  How do I get the DB to assign new sequential PKs for the new records?

Comment: Switching identity on and off in Entity Framework is not straightforward http://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342

Comment: But it can be done: http://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317799

Comment: It does not seem practical. I have abandoned this effort.

Comment: Another approach is make it an identity field from the start and set `IDENTITY INSERT OFF` during the initial import